# Question about Linear transformations within another Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a question about linear transformations and I got stuck. And the question is:

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $B$ = $\left\{v_1,v_2, \dots, v_n\right\}$ be a basis for $V$. If $T$ and $L$ are linear transformations from $V$ to $V$, then $[TL(v)]_B = [T]_B[L]_B[v]_B$ for all $v \in V$.

So far what I have is,

Since $L(v) = L(c_1v_1+ \dots +c_nv_n) =
L(c_1v_1)+ \dots +L(c_nv_n)$

$c$'s are in $V$

then

$$[TL(v)]_B = [T(L(c_1v_1)+ \dots +T(L(c_nv_n)]_B = [ \sum_i (T(L(c_iv_i))) ]_B = [ \sum_i (T(c_iL(v_i)) ]_B$$

and this is where I get stuck. So basically this looks like a linear transformation within a linear transformation (I think). Can someone please lead me towards the right direction to get $[T]_B[L]_B[v]_B$.

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $[L]_B$ and $[v]_B$? Writing this down might help you solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: take the basis vector $v_k$ then $[L(v_k)]_{B}=[L]_{B}[v_k]$  can you prove this? now apply $T$ on $L(v_k)$ and get the result

Comment: I'm sorry, that flew right by my head. Why are we introducing a new basis v sub k?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.  I've modified your post to use the site's markup - you might like to check in case I've made any mistakes!